# AES-XTS: find key from ciphertext and plaintext

Tags: aes, xts

Let's say I have a plaintext, the corresponding ciphertext encrypted using AES-XTS, and the initialization vectors. Is there any way - not brute force, of course - to compute the key?

Even if there's no known way, feel free to share articles on the subject

Comment: There is no known efficient key-recovery attack against AES, no matter the mode of operation.

Comment: All known ways to obtain the key require more input; like, the power consumption over time of the device that performed the computation.

Comment: Ah, I just stumbled upon http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3952/is-it-possible-to-obtain-aes-128-key-from-a-known-ciphertext-plaintext-pair?rq=1 - sorry for the duplicate! Thanks for the answers