# Is it possible to do a known-plaintext attack with this set up of AES CTR mode?

Tags: aes, ctr

Is it possible to perform a known-plaintext attack to extract the key from AES byte encryption?

The encryption is setup with the following two lines:

```
ctr = Counter.new(128)
crypt = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)
```

And we have both the plaintext and the ciphertext

Comment: No mode of operation should ever leak the AES key as it is protected by the block cipher itself. If it is leaked then it is because of a faulty protocol or a side channel attack on the block cipher implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simply no;

The known-plaintext attack on AES-CTR mode will reveal the encrypted output of the AES
$$c_i = p_i \oplus E_k(ctr+i)$$
$$ c_i \oplus p_i = E_k(ctr+i)$$

and since in the counter mode, we know the counter values (input to the AES in CTR mode), we can see this as known-plaintext attack on ECB mode.

The possibility of [known-plaintext attack on AES in ECB mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/63889/61539) is given lately as;

> **No**. This is what is referred to as a known plaintext attack, and secure block ciphers are designed to prevent exactly this kind of attack. This answer on the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/57428) goes into more detail about the notion of IND-CPA ("indistinguishability") which AES is conjectured to meet and how that implies that a known plaintext attack is impossible.

Comment: What do you mean? The linked answer says no, but i don't know what $E_k$ is.

Comment: usually, we writte $AES(key, etc.)$  as $E_k(plaintext)$. Yes, the answer is no. Your writing is coding style.