# An unbreakable Hill cipher?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, perfect-secrecy, hill-cipher

Why don't we use a Hill cipher of 100 × 100? Or even bigger? That would be close to unbreakable.

The number of possible keys in a 2 × 2 Hill cipher is 157248. For 100 × 100 the number is beyond limits.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Hill cipher is vulnerable to [known-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack). Once the attacker gets $n$ plaintext/ciphertext pair it can break the cipher by solving a system of linear equations. Consider AES, it is not proved but considered secure against known-plaintext attack, see [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/63883/18298) for details.

And, also, key size itself doesn't represent the security. High key sizes are necessary but not sufficient. As an example from history, [Enigma](http://wiki.franklinheath.co.uk/index.php/Enigma/Key_Length) was beyond its time as having around $87$ to $88$-bit key size which is greater than the key size of DES. We have already know that Enigma is broken.

---

Answer to comment: We work in [Kerckhoffs's principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) and are not accepting security by obscurity. So the attacker knows everything but the key.

Answer (score -1):

Everything said by @kelalaka is true, but I have proposed a Hill Cipher variant which resolves the vulerability of some attacks like Known Plaintext Attack and Chosen Plaintext Attack.

Allow me to reference myself:

> "The Hill Cipher is a classical example of a cryptosystem with
> interesting properties, namely that it implements the **diffusion**
> and **confusion** concepts coined by Shannon as essential properties
> for ciphers; nonetheless, its basic form is vulnerable to **KPAs**.
> This dissertation presents an efficient method to generate nonsingular
> key matrices, based on the Gauss-Jordan elimination procedure, which
> provides means to generate a new matrix per each block submitted to
> encryption.
>
> **RKHC**, described along this dissertation, uses that method and adds a step to both the encryption and decryption algorithms to deal with
> messages containing patterns (e.g., a sequence of zeros), in order to
> increase their strength against **KPAs**, **CPAs** and **CCAs**.
>
> A performance evaluation of a non-optimized implementation in the C
> programming language of RKHC is also included, compared with those of
> optimized implementations of AES and Salsa20, along with a discussion
> of its security and limitations under the well-known cryptanalysis
> attacks. The claim that the proposed method embeds randomness with
> high entropy into the generated matrices and ciphertext is
> corroborated by results of the TestU01 library for stringent
> randomness statistical tests".

By the way, I tested this several times, and believe me, 100x100 matrix generation would be very time-consuming. As you can see I used 32x32 and 64x64 matrices.

You can find the source code and the full document on my github: https://github.com/mafone/rkhc.

Comment: The [description](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mafone/RKHC/master/RKHC_document.pdf#page=59) rightly states that _"the generation of the pseudo-random mask and key matrix should use a CSPRNG each"_. OK, but with a CSPRNG (and a single one), we can make a stream cipher, and it's CPA secure under the hypothesis used to prove CPA security of RHKC, with lower computational cost. That severely limits the practical interest of RHKC.

Comment: There is also the issue of which CSPRNG you'd use.  Are there any at all with a (usable) seed size of >= 256 bits?

Comment: Notice that the Hill Cipherpresented here is a block cipher, not a stream cipher which is another topic. Also despite being faster the stream ciphers do not provide data integrity by design. You can read a little bit about their difference, starting from here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/334/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-stream-versus-block-ciphers

Comment: Is this even a Hill cipher anymore? Is your proposal beyond the scope of the question?

Comment: HC variant, a variant introduces variations. Not  original HC anymore.