# Is it possible to recover the key to a decrypted file?

Tags: encryption, keys, initialization-vector, rijndael

Is it possible to recover the key to a decrypted file if you have the initialization vector and it uses RijndaelManaged in CBC mode? If so how?

The file I want to recover the key from is a xml that looks like this without encryption. It has a xml element called Test.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test />
```

When it is encrypted with the key *`stackoverflow`* (73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc = md5 hash) and the initialization vector below, the file look like this *`¥4!¬Hw[î!71ôtž|!¢¬TÞ;u?þª-†•ÈÏ‰eßŽKtSsbZ®ÕµR©Ù«í‹`*:

[image: File looks like this]

Initialization vector:

```
byte[] iv = new byte[]
{
    55, 66, 77, 192, 57, 100, 11, 111,
    25, 86, 96, 66, 22, 122, 133, 43
};
```

Is it possible to reverse the key from that or are it bulletproof?

Comment: No ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: are you sure?? xD @kelalaka

Comment: Depends on the encryption mode. If the mode has a relationship between the key and IV (i.e. it is a very bad mode you shouldn't use) then maybe. Question as stated does not have enough information, but if the encryption was done using sane parameters and modes then no.

Comment: More duplicates: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1512, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/63883

Comment: it uses CBC mode and padding value PKCS7 is that going to make a differents? :) @puzzlepalace

Comment: @lovemyencryptedxml Please refrain from cross posting the same question to different stackexchanges