# Is it safe to store AES encrypted string and the original string in plaintext next to each other?

Tags: aes

I have a server app that stores encrypted payload (`$textPayload`) that users encrypted on their side (The server is just stores is and serves it).
Users can use multiple encryption keys for different payloads (`$textPayload`)- the server doesn't know.
I am thinking about how to implement editing.

One approach I came up with was generating a random string (`$editTokenPlain`) on the client, encrypting it (`$editToken`) with the same key and storing both `$editTokenPlain` and `$editToken` next to the sensitive encrypted payload (`$textPayload`).
Then user would receive the edit token(`$editTokenPlain`), encrypt it and send it together with the edited payload and if the encrypted token matched the encrypted value on the server - then the payload would be updated.

My question is: If I have 2 encrypted texts(`$textPayload`,`$editToken`) with the same encryption key (using AES) and 1 decrypted text `$editTokenPlain` - can someone derive the encryption key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to find the key for AES ECB if I have a list of plaintext and corresponding ciphertext?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/63883/is-it-possible-to-find-the-key-for-aes-ecb-if-i-have-a-list-of-plaintext-and-cor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about is called a known plaintext attack, and any block cipher worth its salt will be resistant to it. So yes, it should be safe.